# Using dirac delta function with composite integrand

Tags: integration, physics, dirac-delta

I have a short dirac delta type question, which involves a dirac delta composite function. Can anyone see how the following is equivalent (given in bra-ket notation): 
$$| \theta_0, \phi_0 \rangle \langle \theta_0, \phi_0| = \int \sin \theta d \theta d \phi \delta(\theta -\theta_0) \delta[\sin \theta( \phi - \phi_0)]| \theta, \phi \rangle \langle \theta, \phi |$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \delta(ax)f(x)=\frac{1}{a}f(0)$$
Then, integrating over $\phi$ $$\int \sin \theta d \theta \delta(\theta -\theta_0) \int d \phi \delta[\sin \theta( \phi - \phi_0)]| \theta, \phi \rangle \langle \theta, \phi |=\int \sin \theta d \theta \frac{1}{\sin\theta}\delta(\theta -\theta_0) | \theta, \phi_0 \rangle \langle \theta, \phi_0 |$$
Now integrating over theta, yields $$\int d \theta \delta(\theta -\theta_0) | \theta, \phi_0 \rangle \langle \theta, \phi_0 |= | \theta_0, \phi_0 \rangle \langle \theta_0, \phi_0 |$$